# 'sum()' function gives different result

Tags: r, sum

The following is my code:

```
phi=0.5

a1<-0 
a2<-c()

set.seed(1)
for(u in 1:100){ 
  a<-rgamma(1,shape = 1/phi, scale = phi) 
  a1<-a1+a 
  a2<-c(a2,a) 
  }


a1-sum(a2)
# [1] 1.421085e-14
```

Which is correct?

Comment: try `all.equal(a1, sum(a2))` and `all.equal(0, a1-sum(a2))`

Comment: Yes, I agree, but which is the correct one or more accurate one?

Comment: Neither are exactly correct.  Both are correct when it comes to a floating-point computation.